# What's wrong with this definition?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definition

This is a definition for a sequence $x_n$ verconges (This is just an arbitrary word) to a number x.

[image]

If you carefully dissect the definition, it is inverse definition of a convergence of a sequence.
It seemed to me that this is giving the same meaning as the original definition gives: You are giving N, if $\epsilon$ ensures the condition, thus when $n>N$ the term $x_n$ wedges into $L-\epsilon<x_n<L+\epsilon$. And if for every $N$, such $\epsilon$ can be found we can say that sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$. (That means verconge = converge)

My question is, first of all, is my understanding of this definition is equal to the sequence convergence definition true? Secondly, if it is, why we don't use this instead of the original one?

Comment: It seems to mean that all terms of the sequence are in some *bounded* set that conatins the point $x$

Comment: Any bounded sequence "verconverges" to every real number.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi are there unbounded sequences that *verconge* to any thing ?

Comment: @Physor No, the definition implies that the sequence remains in $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ after the rank $N$ (and there are only a finite number of ranks to consider before that).

Comment: @Bora The statement "And if for every $N$, such $\epsilon$ can be found we can say that sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$" is false. They key point is that one value of $\epsilon$ is not enough; the entire point of convergence is "arbitrary closeness", hence the importance of considering values of $\epsilon > 0$ so that the bounding distance can be made as small as one desires.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $x_n=(-1)^n$. For $\epsilon=100$ you can "verconverge" to a lot of values...

In the original definition you get arbitrary close to $x$ at some point (so for every $\epsilon$ there is "this point") whereas here you get $\epsilon$-close for a specific $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

A vercongent sequence need not have a unique "limit". For convergent sequences in $\mathbb R$, say, the limit is unique. Hence, different notions.

Answer (score 0):

Take the sequence $(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots)$, and put $x=0$. Does there exist an $\epsilon>0$, such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$?

Yes, take $\epsilon = 2$. Since $x_n$ can be only $0$ or $1$, you definitely have for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that $|x_n-0|<2$ for $n\geq N$. So $(x_n)$ is vercongent to $x$.

Things to think about:

- Are all convergent sequences vercongent?
- Can an unbounded sequence be
  vercongent?
- Are all bounded sequences vercongent?
- Can you verconge to multiple values?